# Asp.net 5 mvc 6 Entity Framework 7 database first

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, edmx

I noticed that this type of project does not support files edmx.
What is the right way to develop a project in Asp.net 5 MVC 6 using Entity Framwork 7?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: You should take a look at this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456815(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: The link above speaks about "Model First" and use  ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer. I want to use "Data Base First" and MVC 6 seems not to support edmx files.

Comment: I use Entity Framework 7

Answer (score 1):

Currently(as of EF 7, RC1) Database First support is still in development. More info on roadmap page [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap) and on EF Design meeting notes [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Entity-Framework-Design-Meeting-Notes).

Since this is in development there are ways to try this and more info and tutorial on commands can be found at official documentation page [here](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/staging/getting-started/full-dotnet/existing-db.html).

Comment: Thank you. Using EF6 is the same. It seems to have no support in MVC 6 for edmx technology

Comment: For EF6 Database First to work u have to use latest tooling inside Visual Studio. You can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx). To work with Database First in EF7 you don't need VS, only dnx - on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that EF7 kill EDMX. You now have Code First-style POCOs tied to an existing database, without an EDMX file in sight. The EF Power Tools Visual Studio extension can be installed to generate all of this directly from existing database.EF Power Tools Visual Studio extension actually doesn't support vs 2015